# Show events that only pertain to current month in fullcalendar?

Tags: jquery, html, coldfusion

I have found suggest approaches to be able to hide out events that do not pertain in the current month: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/437.

I would like to use the following code to hide events. I have tried to implement the following code below:

```
    //what month the event is

var theEventMonth = event.start.getUTCMonth();
//what month we're viewing
var showingMonth = t.start.getMonth();

if(theEventMonth != showingMonth){
    className = 'hiddenEvent ';
}else{
    className = 'fc-event fc-event-hori ';
}
---
```

The following is the image that shows events that should not be appearing in the current month:

[image]

I am not sure where in the following code should be added in the following code (I am using Coldfusion and Mura):

```
    <cffunction name="FullCalendar">

    <cfscript>

        var calendarid = $.getbean('content').loadby(title='Regal Events').getcontentid();


    </cfscript>
    <cfsavecontent variable="local.str">
        <cfoutput>           

                 <div id="UpcomingCal" class="calendarResize">
                 </div>
         <script>

         mura.loader()
            .loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css",{media:'all'})
            <!---.loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-custom.css",{media:'all'})--->
            .loadcss("#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css",{media:'print'})
            .loadjs(
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js",
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js",
                "#$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/gcal.js",
                function(){
                     $('##UpcomingCal').fullCalendar({
                         weekMode: 'variable',
                         eventSources: [
                            {
                                url: '#variables.$.siteConfig('requirementspath')#/fullcalendar/proxy.cfc?calendarid=#esapiEncode("javascript",CalendarID)#'
                                , type: 'POST'
                                , data: {
                                    method: 'getFullCalendarItems'
                                    , calendarid: '#esapiEncode("javascript",CalendarID)#'
                                    , siteid: '#variables.$.content('siteid')#'
                                    , categoryid: '#esapiEncode('javascript',variables.$.event('categoryid'))#'
                                    , tag: '#esapiEncode('javascript',variables.$.event('tag'))#'
                                }
                                <!---, color: '#this.calendarcolors[colorIndex].background#'
                                , textColor: '#this.calendarcolors[colorIndex].text#'--->
                                , error: function() {
                                    $('##mura-calendar-error').show();
                                }
                            },
                        ]
                    });
                }
               )
         </script>

        </cfoutput>
    </cfsavecontent>
    <cfreturn local.str />
</cffunction
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view)
{
    // console.log(event);
    // console.log(event.start.month());
    // console.log(view.start.month());
    // console.log(element);
    // console.log(view.intervalStart.month());
    if(event.start.month() !== view.intervalStart.month()) { return false; }
},
```

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow, Dherendra!

A few words of explanation to your answer would be very nice!

Comment: Add some explanatory sentences into your answer. Make it as clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this. This works for me.

```
dayRender:function(date,cell,view){ // added view in arguments 
var startmonth = view.start.getMonth()+1;
if( month == startmonth )
{
  your codes;
}
```

Comment: by you code, the code where the calendar is being generating?

Answer (score 0):

As I go through document of full **calendar js**, I didn't find any solution for it. So use it like below.

```
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();


    var month = Array();
    for (var i = 0;i < event_days.length; i++){

   var cal_month = m + 1;
   var currnt_month = event_days[i].date.split("-").map(Number);

   if(currnt_month[1] == cal_month){
        var monthSource = new Object();
        monthSource.title = '<span style="color: #ff1103">'+event_days[i].base_currency+'&nbsp;&nbsp;'+event_days[i].d_adult_sharing+'</span><br><a  class="btn btn-primary btn-xs book_click" >Book</a>'; 
        monthSource.start = ''+event_days[i].date+'';

        month[i] = monthSource;
      }
    }
```

Where `event_days` is my array which contains all dates on which I want to show my events.

And for next month or previous month I use.

```
$(document).on("click", ".fc-button-next" , function(){

   alert('nextis clicked, do something');
});
```

I hope this will help.